# regular expression for detect formated name of images

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, detection

I need to detect image with **ended** by dimension (NUMxNUM) or some static words like (icon,small,normal,large)

stared items is currect rule:

```
/test/abcd/files/01_aa_100x200.jpg *
/test/abcd/files/abcd_221x105.jpg *
/test/abcd/files/01_aa_icon.jpg *
/test/abcd/files/01aa_iconblabla.jpg
/test/abcd/files/aa_small.jpg *
/test/abcd/files/aa0_test.jpg
```

i use this but dosnt work currectly

```
\/([0-9a-z-]{1,})\/([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})\/(.+)\_[x0-9|small|icon|normal|large](.+)\.(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)
```

[Demo](https://regexr.com/3li17)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

`\/([0-9a-z-]+)\/([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})\/(.+)\_(\d+x\d+|small|icon|normal|large)\.(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QsNsRT/3)